# Generate images with ImageMagick without saving to file but still display them on website

Tags: php, javascript, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

This is my ImageMagick code which works fine on my webserver by creating new image with the file name 'coloured_font.png' in a default directory ...

```
<?php 
$cmd = " -background none -pointsize 60 -font Times-Roman -fill red ".
 " -strokewidth 1 -stroke black label:\"google\" ";
exec("convert $cmd coloured_font.png");
?>
```

But now I am running ImageMagick on Windows which will not create any image files in a default folder but ImageMagick applications runs fine(i have tested by creating thumbnail). So now my idea is to display 'coloured_font.png' in the browser screen without saving it anywhere else... so please can anyone help me to create and display image on the screen without saving it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the special `inline:` format of images (which ImageMagick supports for reading files too). This format is a base64 encoding of binary data.

On the (Linux) commandline:

```
my_base64_png="$(
convert               \
    -background none  \
    -pointsize 60     \
    -font Times-Roman \
    -fill red         \
    -strokewidth 1    \
    -stroke black     \
     label:\"google\" \
     png:fd:1         \
 |                    \
 base64  -i -  -o -)"
```

This command uses several special tricks ImageMagick and the shell have up in their sleeves:

- using the format hint `png:` to tell it that the output should be in PNG format;
- using *stdout* as its output channel (instead of a file) by specifiying `fd:1`;
- piping the output directly into *stdin* of the `base64` binary to encode the PNG;
- storing the base64 encoded data in the environment variable `my_base64_png`.

Now in your HTML inlining the base64 image data (which should work in all modern, but **doesn't work in older browsers**):

```
 <IMG SRC="data:image/png;base64,
         echo "$(my_base64_png)"
  ALT="google" WIDTH=214  HEIGHT=57  VSPACE=5 HSPACE=5 BORDER=0 />
```

or

```
 <IMG SRC="data:image/png;base64,
         iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM4AAABJAQMAAABPZIvnAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xh
         BQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwAADqYAAA
         OpgAABdwnLpRPAAAAAZQTFRFAAAA/wAAG/+NIgAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAABYktH
         RACIBR1IAAAACXBIWXMAAABIAAAASABGyWs+AAAB6ElEQVQ4y+3UQY7bIBQG4IeQ
         yqYaLhANV+iyi9FwpS69iGyiLuZYpepF6A1YskC8/uCA7SgZtVI3lcoiivkIxu/9
         MdH/8U+N6el2pk0oFyibWyr1Q3+PlO2NqJV+/BnRPMjcJ9zrfJ/U+zQ9oAvo+QGF
         d+npPqFQn++TXElkrEpEJhAtlTBR6dNHUuzIMhFnEhxAmJDkKxlmt7ATXDDJYcaE
         r4Txqtkl42VYSH+t9KrD9b5nxZeog/LWGVHprGInGWVQUTvjDWXca5KdsowqyGSc
         DrZRlGlQUl4kQwpUjiSS9gI9VdECZhHFQ2I+UE2CHJQfkNxTNKCl0RkURqlLowJK
         1h1p3sjc0CJD39D4BIqD7JvvpH/GAxl2/YSq9mtHSHknga7OKNOHKyEdaFC2Dh1w
         9VSJemBeGuHgMuh24EynK03YM1Lr83OjUle38aVSfTblT424rl4LhdglsUag5RB5
         uBJSJBIiELSzaAeIN0pUlEeZEMeClC4cBuH6mxOlgPjC3uLproUCWfy58WPN/MZR
         86ghc888yNdD0Tj8eAucasl2I5LqX19I7EmEjaYjSb9R/G1SYfQA7ZBuT5H6WwDt
         UAfK1BOJmh/eZnKLeKvZ/vA8qonCpj1h6djfbqvW620Tva36++MXUkNDlFREMVkA
         AAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMTItMDgtMjJUMDg6Mzc6NDUrMDI6MDBTUnmt
         AAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDEyLTA4LTIyVDA4OjM3OjQ1KzAyOjAwIg/B
         EQAAAA50RVh0bGFiZWwAImdvb2dsZSJdcbX4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
  ALT="google" WIDTH=214  HEIGHT=57  VSPACE=5 HSPACE=5 BORDER=0 />
```

It shouldn't be difficult for you to translate this procedure into PHP.   ;-)

As I said, ImageMagick can read this `inline:` format (not used here for reading). But for completeness' sake let me show you how:

```
  convert                                                                   \
        'inline:image/png;data:,
         iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM4AAABJAQMAAABPZIvnAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xh
         BQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwAADqYAAA
         OpgAABdwnLpRPAAAAAZQTFRFAAAA/wAAG/+NIgAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAABYktH
         RACIBR1IAAAACXBIWXMAAABIAAAASABGyWs+AAAB6ElEQVQ4y+3UQY7bIBQG4IeQ
         yqYaLhANV+iyi9FwpS69iGyiLuZYpepF6A1YskC8/uCA7SgZtVI3lcoiivkIxu/9
         MdH/8U+N6el2pk0oFyibWyr1Q3+PlO2NqJV+/BnRPMjcJ9zrfJ/U+zQ9oAvo+QGF
         d+npPqFQn++TXElkrEpEJhAtlTBR6dNHUuzIMhFnEhxAmJDkKxlmt7ATXDDJYcaE
         r4Txqtkl42VYSH+t9KrD9b5nxZeog/LWGVHprGInGWVQUTvjDWXca5KdsowqyGSc
         DrZRlGlQUl4kQwpUjiSS9gI9VdECZhHFQ2I+UE2CHJQfkNxTNKCl0RkURqlLowJK
         1h1p3sjc0CJD39D4BIqD7JvvpH/GAxl2/YSq9mtHSHknga7OKNOHKyEdaFC2Dh1w
         9VSJemBeGuHgMuh24EynK03YM1Lr83OjUle38aVSfTblT424rl4LhdglsUag5RB5
         uBJSJBIiELSzaAeIN0pUlEeZEMeClC4cBuH6mxOlgPjC3uLproUCWfy58WPN/MZR
         86ghc888yNdD0Tj8eAucasl2I5LqX19I7EmEjaYjSb9R/G1SYfQA7ZBuT5H6WwDt
         UAfK1BOJmh/eZnKLeKvZ/vA8qonCpj1h6djfbqvW620Tva36++MXUkNDlFREMVkA
         AAAldEVYdGRhdGU6Y3JlYXRlADIwMTItMDgtMjJUMDg6Mzc6NDUrMDI6MDBTUnmt
         AAAAJXRFWHRkYXRlOm1vZGlmeQAyMDEyLTA4LTIyVDA4OjM3OjQ1KzAyOjAwIg/B
         EQAAAA50RVh0bGFiZWwAImdvb2dsZSJdcbX4AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'              \
  my_decoded.png
```

ImageMagick doesn't require the `image/png;` part of the command (it even ignores it), because it can identify the format anyway through it's own builtin magic database -- but it doesn't hurt either...

Let me also point out that ImageMagick's commandline length is limited to 5000 characters, so reading `inline:` data will not work for larger pictures. (I don't know at the moment what the limitation for inlining image data in HTML is...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply 'kurt' but as i have mentioned iam using windows :( ...so whats the alternative in windows Operating system...but i will try your steps ....lets see wthr i will be able to resolve or not :(

Comment: @Google: It doesn't matter that you're using Windows. You can still translate this into PHP, and that would work on all platforms PHP runs on...

Comment: @Google: In other words: (1) Use the `convert .. | base64 ...` command to generate ouput that you save as a string variable.  (2) Put that string variable's content into your HTML as an inline picture.

Comment: The `<IMG SRC="data:image/png;base64,...` in not supported in older browsers, IE8 has size limit 32 kB

Comment: @Petr: Thanks for the hint about older browsers (I thought I had mentioned that, but obviously not). Also thanks for pointing out the IE8 limit.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `coloured_font.png` with `coloured_font.php` in you html file and create

`coloured_font.php` with this contents:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/png");

echo `convert -background none -pointsize 60 -font Times-Roman -fill red ".
 " -strokewidth 1 -stroke black label:\"google\" png:-`;
```

and thats it! Try to open `coloured_font.php` in your browser!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a temporary file

Steps

1. Create a temporary file, `temp_image.jpg` by running `imagemagick` command in shell
2. Send this as http response

   ```
   $file = 'pathto/temp_image.jpg';
   $type = 'image/jpeg';           // set appropriate type    
   header('Content-Type:'.$type);  // set content type
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
   readfile($file);
   ```
3. Delete `temp_image.jpg`

Suppose this is in `getImage.php`, it can be given as the source of an image tag

```
<img src="pathto/getImage.php" />
```