# Passing 2 stdin arguments to a ImageMagick child_process

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, buffer, stdin, child-process

I have certain limitations that I won't specify that require me to use ImageMagick as a child-process.

I have multiple base 64 strings of jpg files which I want ImageMagick to process.
Specifically I want ImageMagick to join the jpg files together. If I had 2 regular jpg files then from the command line I would use the following format.

```
node convert in_1.jpg in_2.jpg +append out.jpg
```

in a js file I would use

```
var spawn, magicCommands, imagic;
spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
magicCommands = ["in_1.jpg",
                 "in_2.jpg",
                 "+append",
                 "out.jpg"];
imagic = spawn("convert", magicCommands);
```

Now if I wanted to use **1** stdin buffer the following would work

```
    var arrow1JpgBase64, arrow2JpgBase64, arrowBuffer1, arrowBuffer2, magicCommands, imagic;

    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

    arrow1JpgBase64 = "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";
    arrow2JpgBase64 = "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";
    arrowBuffer1 = new Buffer(arrow1JpgBase64, 'base64');
    arrowBuffer2 = new Buffer(arrow2JpgBase64, 'base64');
    magicCommands = ["jpg:",
                     "in_2.jpg",
                     "+append",
                     "out.jpg"];

    imagic = spawn("convert", magicCommands);
    imagic.stdin.write(arrowBuffer1);
    imagic.stdin.end();

    imagic.on('exit', function (code) {
        if (code === 0) {
            exec("open out.jpg");
        } else {
            console.log("error code: " + code);
        }
    }); // end of on exit
```

So far so good, but I want to use **both** of the buffers and not just **1** of them.  So if I replace the `"in_2.jpg",` line with `"jpg:",` then how do I have to change the rest of the script to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: Gotta dash, but maybe you can use the `fd:` handler in ImageMagick and put one buffer on `fd:3` and another on say `fd:4`... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#fd

Comment: If you already have a base64 string (and that's < 5000 characters), way not [pass it as an argument directly](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#inline) w/ `inline:data:image/jpeg;base64,...`?

Comment: @emcconville I was trying to do that same thing myself but it seems not to work any more, I tried Kurt's example here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12067952/2836621 and the example under **ASIDE**  here... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#inline It all seems broken in IM v6.9.2-5.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  @Mark Setchell, your reply looks very promising but can you write some code showing how to assign an fd to a buffer, sorry for showing my ignorance!

Comment: @emcconville, your reply would be ideal but the 5000 char limit is too restrictive.

Comment: Another option may be to create a fifo, with `mkfifo` and write your base64 string into the fifo and make IM read one file from `stdin` and the other from a fifo... `convert jpg: fifo -append result.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I shall look into that tomorrow, (I actually need to process an unknown amount of strings so I would have to make a fifo for all of them except the 1st).  Your 1st reply sounded very promising, see this [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=13100)  I just don't have a clue how to apply it in practice.  Any sample code? or reason not to go that way?

Answer (score 4):

As Mark Setchell pointed out in the comments, using ImageMagick's `fd:` protocol will work.

```js
var spawnOptions = {
      stdio: [
        0, // stdin,
        1, // stdout
        2, // stderr
        'pipe', // arrowBuffer1
        'pipe'  // arrowBuffer2
      ]
};
magic = spawn("convert", magicCommands, spawnOptions);
```

This opens `fd:3` & `fd:4` for piping. I'm not failure with the [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) family, but there usually a way to pass a resource in addition to [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe).

*For your code*

Update the `magickCommands` variable to read from new `fd`'s, and write directly to new `pipes`

```js
magicCommands = ["fd:3",
                 "fd:4",
                 "+append",
                 "out.jpg"];

// ...
imagic.stdio[3].write(arrowBuffer1);
imagic.stdio[4].write(arrowBuffer2);
imagic.stdio[3].end();
imagic.stdio[4].end();
```

Comment: I am getting a message that imagic.stdio[3] is undefined and I can't write to it.  I think though this is getting close

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what these *"limitations"* are, or what we are trying to avoid or work around, but the following technique of streaming multiple files into one may help you:

```
# Make a red block
convert -size 50x50 xc:red multi.miff

# Make a green block, but APPEND INTO A SINGLE STREAM
convert -size 50x50 xc:lime miff:- >> multi.miff

# Make a blue block, but APPEND INTO A SINGLE STREAM
convert -size 50x50 xc:blue miff:- >> multi.miff

# Tell IM to convert and append multiple images in single stream 
convert multi.miff +append result.png
```

[image]

Also, if you change the last command above to the following, IM will delete the file `multi.miff` as soon as it has finished with it - i.e. tidy up for you!

```
convert ephemeral:multi.miff +append result.png
```

Comment: Thanks again, the limitations I was referring to is that I can't use native (c++ based) node modules, so that excludes me using lwip or other possible options.  What I am really looking for is to avoid unnecessary writing to the hard disk.  The buffers already exist so if I could just pass them as arguments it would be better than saving them as files and then deleting the files afterwards.  I shall post another tread about getting an fd of a buffer if there is such a thing!

Comment: Ok, I am getting closer to understanding I think... have you considered a small RAMdisk for temporary files?

Comment: Nope, it's for a clients system, for multiple installs. I shall probably just resort to creating and erasing the file.  But I'll first have a go at creating buffer streams and the I think they can be referred to by their fd which I  think they have.   I posted a post here http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=13100 but don't understand the answer

Comment: I experimented with the ram disk and I looks like it could be a simple and efficient solution.  I shall use that method and see it my client's IT department has any problem with it.  I'll get back with a report on how it goes.