# How to get the fd of a node buffer if there is such a thing?

Tags: node.js

Coming from this post [Passing 2 stdin arguments to a ImageMagick child_process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655680/passing-2-stdin-arguments-to-a-imagemagick-child-process/33666484#33666484) I am trying to find out if there is and if so how to get the fd of a node buffer.

```
   foo = new Buffer("foo");
```

How to get the fd of  foo?

Comment: Buffers don't have fds; they're just (binary) arrays in memory.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Thanks, I very much suspected that.  Any input on the link I posted above would be appreciated.   Is there a way to pass 2 arguments through stdin?  See over the link for what I mean.